# Return value of function to parameters object in jquery click method

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have the following code:

```
$('a.display').click({
    p1: $(this).attr('href'),
    p2: '#' + $(this).parents().filter(function () {
        return $(this).attr('class') == 'display';
    }).id
}, display);
```

I'm trying to pass the actual values of the functions being performed in object element p1 and p2 to my display function which takes two parameters. Instead it's returning the whole function.  Is there something different I can do to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Seems like an odd technique.. is there a reason you aren't using one of these: http://jsfiddle.net/5s46E/ ?

Answer (score 1):

When using this type of call your parameters are stored in the event object's data property so:

```
function display(event){
  console.log(event.data.p1);
  console.log(event.data.p2);
}
```

but also note that `this` in this part of your code:

```
{
    p1: $(this).attr('href'),
    p2: '#' + $(this).parents().filter(function () {
        return $(this).attr('class') == 'display';
    }).id
}
```

does not represent the DOM element being selected so:

```
$(this).attr("href") //etc
```

is going to give you undefined